# Python/Django tests running only one test at a time

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a unittest for my view

```
class TestFromAllAdd(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['staging_accounts_user.json',
        'staging_main_category.json',
        'staging_main_dashboard.json',
        'staging_main_location.json',
        'staging_main_product.json',
        'staging_main_shoppinglist.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.c = Client()
        self.c.login(username='admin', password='admin')

    def from_all_products_html404_test(self):
        request = self.factory.post('main/adding_from_all_products', {'product_id': ''})
        request.user = User.objects.get(username= 'admin')
        response = adding_from_all_products(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

But I have a few more classes with tests and I cant run them all at the same time:
`python manage.py test main` doesnt run tests, but if i run;
`python manage.py test main.TestFromAllAdd.from_all_products_html404_test` , runs one test;

Comment: Is there a question in there?  The very last sentence seems to answer what's in the title...

Comment: The question was that I wanted to write python manage.py test main and run ALL tests

Comment: If you want to run all tests in a django app named "main", then `python manage.py test main` is the correct way to do it.  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Unittest methods need to begin with the word `test` (not end with it). Your method should be called `test_from_all_products_html404`.

Answer (score 1):

Python testing requires that all methods start with test word, so my method must be renamed test_from_all_products_html404_test